# Trying to identify if a data injection method has a name already

Tags: algorithm, graph

Lets say we have a class  "Car" than has different pieces of data ( maker, model, color, fabrication date, registration date, etc). The class has no method to get data, but it knows to as for it from another object (sent via constructor, let's cal it for short DS).- and the same for when needing to update changes.

A method getColor() would be implemented like this

```
if(! this->loaded('color')){

 this->askDS('color') // this will do the necesarry work to generate a request to DS

}

return this->information('color');
```

Nothing too fancy so far. No comes the part i want to find out if it has a name, or if there are libraries / frameworks that do this already.

DS has a list of methods registered dinamically based on the class that needs data. For car we have:

1. input: car serial number, output: method to use to read the numbers to extract raw values
2. input: car raw color value, output: color code
3. input: car color code, manufacturer, year, mode, output:human-readable color (for example navy blue)

Now, DS or any method does not have an ordered list of using command to start from serial number and return the color blue, but if can construct a chain of methods that from one set of data, it can run them in order and get the desired data.

For our example above, DS runs 1,2,3 in that order and injects the data resulted from all methods into the class object that needed it.

Now if the car needs registration info, we have method  (4) that gets that from the police database with an api request.

So, given:
- a type of model (class/object)
- a list of methods that take a fixed list of input(object properties) and give out a fixed list of output (object properties)
- a class DS that can glue the methods and run the needed ones for a model to get from property A (serial) to properby B (human readable colour) without the model or DS having a preconfigured way to get this data but finding it as needed.

does this have a name or is it already implemented somewhere ?

I've implemented a very basic prototype and it works very nice and i think this implementation method has useful features:

- if you have a set of methods that do sql queries and then your app switches to using an api, you only need to change the methods and don't have to touch any other part of the application
- when looking for a chain of methods that resolve the 'need' the object has, you can find a method chain, run it, if it fails keep looking for another list of methods based on the currently available data - so if you have multiple sources for a piece of data, it can try multiple versions
- starting from the above paragraph i could start with an app that only has sql queries for data retrieval - when i find out a part of the app overloads the sql server i could add a method to retrieve data from cache with a lower cost than the one from database (or multiple layered caches, each with different costs)
- i could probably add business logi in the mix the same ways as cache, and based on the user location / options present different data
- this requires less coding overall, and decouples the data source from the object, making each piece easier to mock/test
- what is needed to make this fast is a caching solution for the discovered method chains, since matching hundreds of thousands of methods per model type would be time-consuming but I don't think this is very hard to do - just store all found chains in memory as you find them and some metadata to be able to resume a search from any point in time - when you update the methods, just clear the cache, take a performance hit for the first requests

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like a somewhat roundabout way of doing [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Quote:

> "Passing the service to the client, rather than allowing a client to
>   build or find the service, is the fundamental requirement of the
>   pattern."

Depending on what language you're using, there should be several Dependency Injection frameworks/libraries available.